# Interface not found error would keep appearing after importing it

Tags: php

I'm developing a REST API in PHP and when importing to a class that implements an interface, and fatal error would keep on appearing even though the import is correct.

I have been playing with some routes, changing the interface to the same directory, but such error kept showing up.

My project structure is:

```
gguaguas
--- client
--- --- customResponses
--- --- --- ClientNotFoundResponse.php
--- --- get.php
--- libs
--- --- Response.php
```

There are more directories and files, but they have not been represented for the sake of simplicity.

Interface `Response`:

```php
<?php

interface Response {

    public function get();

}
```

Class `ClientNotFoundException`

```php
<?php

include('../../libs/Response.php');

class ClientNotFoundResponse implements Response {

    public function get() {
        return array('message' => 'ERR: client not found.');
    }
}
```

file `client/get.php`:

```php
<?php

include_once '../libs/Database.php';
include_once '../libs/Checker.php';
include_once 'customResponses/ClientNotFoundResponse.php';

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");

Database::createDatabaseInstance();

if (Checker::areSetAndValidFields($_POST['id'])) {
    $data = Database::executeSQL(sprintf("SELECT * from clients where id=%d", $_POST['id']));
    if ($data->rowCount() > 0) {
        foreach($data as $row) {
            echo json_encode(array("clientName" => $row['clientName'], "cif" => $row['cif'], "email" => $row['email'], "nickname" => $row['nickname']));
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode((new ClientNotFoundResponse())->get());
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode((new MissingFieldsOrInvalidCharactersResponse())->get());
}
```

The exception is raised when trying to execute:

`echo json_encode((new ClientNotFoundResponse())->get());`

And the actual result is:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  include(../../libs/Response.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\gguaguas\client\customResponses\ClientNotFoundResponse.php</b> on line
<b>3</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  include(): Failed opening '../../libs/Response.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\gguaguas\client\customResponses\ClientNotFoundResponse.php</b> on line
<b>3</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Interface 'Response' not found in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\gguaguas\client\customResponses\ClientNotFoundResponse.php</b> on line
<b>5</b>
<br />
```

The expected output obviously is to resolve such import correctly and return the JSON:

```
{
   "message" : "ERR: Client not found."
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use autoloading via composer if you would like an easy way to handle it. If you want to manually include/require your classes, you should use a fixed starting point, since if you use rewrites to alter your URL's it wont work. I would recommend something like \__DIR\__.'/../<some_class>' or if you have some kind of constant or static class to get a base directory.

Answer (score 0):

It say "failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .... "

are you sure this line has the correct path?

include('../../libs/Response.php');

Use the full path to your project by using a constant.

Otherwise and better way is to use autoloading! -> spl_autoload_register

Comment: By using an absolute path the problem is solved. The file does exist in such directory. I do think it has something to do with relative routes. Maybe PHP is not a big fan of the two consecutive dots for referencing a parent directory.

Comment: @TDRS you could test <?php include($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/path/to/file') ?>